# why console log doesn't show in executions when ran by external webapp instead of head?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have an external html form that uses fetch to run the doPost in GAS to fill a google sheet, I have placed a Logger.log at the top of it. When I run doPost in the editor I can see the Logger.log but running it from my html form, I don't see it anymore, there isn't any arrow for me to click to see the log. why is this happening?

```
function doPost (e) {

  Logger.log("hi")
      // do stuff
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Known issue. Add a star to Google tracker as mentioned in the linked answers.